# CSS: border-box not working as expected on a table?

Tags: css

I'm trying to give a table a left margin, and set the width of the **table plus its margin** to 100% of the containing div.

Normally I'd do this with `width: 100%` and `box-style: border-box`, but this doesn't seem to be working on a table.

Here's my CSS:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 2em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: table; /* tried adding this but doesn't seem to help */
}
```

You can see the problem here in a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7C66d/

I can see it in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Read the specs again, `border-box` does not include margin

Comment: Ah. Is there any equivalent that does include margin?

Comment: No, but you can use `calc()` on the width, and subtract the margin amt.

Comment: Thanks - I ended up using `calc()`, if you want to submit that as an answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused, you use padding with border-box, not margin.

http://jsfiddle.net/7C66d/4/

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>why is this table</td><td>not border-box</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 2em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a wrapper, you can use `display:block` as it will set the width to 100% by default.

Code:

```
table {
    margin-left: 2em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
}
```